# Como añadir datos en una tabla sin llave primaria?

Tags: base-de-datos

estoy intentando cargar datos a una tabla "Telefono_alumo" en libre base para aprender pero no me deja editar los campos. Esta tabla esta relacionada con una tabla Alumnos, y su cardinalidad es de uno a varios, es decir, un alumno cuenta con varios telefonos, aqui una captura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven, debajo de los nombres de los capos deberían aparecer las casillas para cargar los datos en la tabla, pero no aparecen, no tira error ni nada, solo no me deja cargar los datos.

Comment: Hola. ¿A qué te refieres cuando hablas de *cargar datos*? Explica la acción que realizas (¿una consulta INSERT?, ¿cargarlos desde un archivo?, ¿restaurar un backup?, etc) Como ves, hay mil formas de *cargar datos*. Explica también si da algún error.

Comment: Hola, me refería a que debajo de los nombre de los campos suelen aparecer las casillas para insertar los datos directamente en la tabla, pero en esta no me funciona.